# Fluent NHibernate, joined-subclass mapping

Tags: c#, .net, nhibernate, fluent-nhibernate, orm

I'm trying to map a joined-subclass scenario using Fluent NHibernate.
I have a class Entity defined in the namespace Core, and a class
SubClass : Entity in the namespace SomeModule

Now I obviously don't want class Entity to know about its derived
types, the SomeModules namespace references Core - not the other way
around.

All the examples I've been able to find use something like:

```
public class EntityMap : ClassMap<Entity> {
    public EntityMap() {
        Id(x => x.Id)

        var subClassMap = JoinedSubClass<SubClass>("SubClassId", sub => sub.Map(x => x.Id));

        subClassMap.Map(x => x.SomeProperty)
        ...
    }
}
```

This simply won't work in my situation - I need something akin to the
NHibernate xml mapping:

```
<joined-subclass name="SubClass" extends="Entity, Core" >
<key column="SubClassId" foreign-key="FK_KollegiumEntity"/>
<property name="Name" length="255" not-null="true" />
...
</joined-subclass>
```

Has anyone achieved this with Fluent NHibernate?

Answer (score 10):

I think the API has changed since this question was asked, but this works for me:

```
public class SomeSubclassMap : SubclassMap<SomeSubclass> {
    public SomeSubclassMap()
    {
        KeyColumn("SomeKeyColumnID");
        Map(x => x.SomeSubClassProperty);
        ...
    }
}
```

I believe KeyColumn is only required if it's different than 'Baseclassname_id'

Note: There should also be a `ClassMap<SomeBaseClass>` for the base class that SomeSubClass extends.

Comment: +1 for your nice answer. Do you have any idea how to tell Fluent NHibernate that "KeyColumn" should be joined to column "XYZ" in base class table, NOT the primary key column?

Comment: @Milan: I'm just seeing this, sorry for the slow reply.  I'm not aware of a way to specify a different KeyColumn on the base class side -KeyColumn property means just that, the parent/base's primary key column.  I took a look at the docs just in case there was something I may have misunderstood.

Comment: @MilanGardian did you ever find an answer to your question? Can a subclass map back to its parent, but w/o using the parent's ID column?

Comment: @ahsteele unfortunately no, and I stopped using NHibernate since then.

Comment: @MilanGardian hey figured I'd ask! I did end up posting my own question: http://stackoverflow.com/q/12717935/61654. Hopefully I get an answer. ;)

Answer (score 1):

Sorry missed your comment, found this

```
public class SubClassMap : JoinedSubClassPart< SubClass >
{
    public SubClassMap()
        : base("SubClassId")
    {
         Map(x => x.Name); 
         Map(x => x.SomeProperty); 
    }
}
```

Hope it helps if you haven't solved it already.

Answer (score 1):

Magnus (or Prise),

Did you figure out how to use that last example in the parent mapping class? This worked for me but I don't like instantiating the SubClassMap myself:

```
public class EntityMap : ClassMap<Entity> {
 public EntityMap() {
    Id(x => x.Id)
    AddPart(new SubClassMap()); // Adds the subclass mapping!
 }
}

public class SubClassMap : JoinedSubClassPart<SubClass>
{
    public SubClassMap()
        : base("SubClassId")
    {
         Map(x => x.Name); 
         Map(x => x.SomeProperty); 
    }
}
```

Which produced a query similar to:

```
SELECT
  this_.Id as Id2_2
  this_.Name as Name3_2
  this_.SomeProperty as SomeProperty3_2
FROM
  SubClass this_ inner join
    Entity this_1 on this_.Id=this_1.Id
```

Comment: Seems Add Part is now Obsolete...?

Answer (score 0):

Hello did some thing like it a few days ago.

```
public class EntityMap : ClassMap<Entity> {
 public EntityMap() {
    Id(x => x.Id)

    JoinedSubClass<SubClass>("SubClassId", sub => { 
          sub.Map(x => x.Name); 
          sub.Map(x => x.SomeProperty); 
    });
 }
}
```

Hope it helps

Comment: Your proposed solution doesn't solve my problem, which is to separate the mappings of Entity and SubClass.

Answer (score 0):

Magnus, I was having the exact same type of issue, and your suggestion sorted it.

The second parameter to JoinedSubClass takes a SubClassPart Action against your object of type SubT.  Hence you only need to then map the additional fields on your subclassed object.

That previous example is mapping an Id, so i'm guessing thats a different id to the value the  base and subclass join on, otherwise you'd start to see SqlParameterCollection errors being through.