# How can I map to a joined subclass with a different column than the id of parent?

Tags: nhibernate, fluent-nhibernate, nhibernate-mapping, fluent-nhibernate-mapping

I am working with a [brownfield](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Brownfield_%28software_development%29) database and am trying to configure a subclass map which joins to its subclasses with a column other than that of the specified id. The `login` table has a primary key column `login_sk` which I'd like to use as its id. It joins to two tables via a `login_cust_id` column (to make things more fun the corresponding columns in the adjoining tables are named differently). If I setup `login_cust_id` as the id of the UserMap it joins to its subclasses as expected. For what I hope are obvious reasons I do not want to use `login_cust_id` as the id for my User objects.

```cs
public class UserMap : ClassMap<IUser>
{
    public UserMap()
    {
        Table("login");
        Id(x => x.Id).Column("login_sk"); // want to setup map like this

        // if used instead this works for subclass joining / mapping
        // Id(x => x.Id).Column("login_cust_id");
        // would prefer to only reference login_cust_id for subclass mapping
    }
}

public class CustomerUserMap : SubclassMap<CustomerUser>
{
    public CustomerUserMap()
    {
        Table("customer");
        Map(c => c.DisplayName, "cust_mail_name");
        Map(c => c.RecordChangeName, "cust_lookup_name");
        KeyColumn("cust_id");
    }
}

public class EntityUserMap : SubclassMap<EntityUser>
{
    public EntityUserMap()
    {
        Table("entity");
        Map(c => c.DisplayName, "entity_name");
        KeyColumn("entity_id");
    }
}
```

What I'd like to do is only use the `login_cust_id` column when joining to subclasses. Is there a fluent mapping setting that allows me to specify this? If not a fluent mapping is there a regular NHibernate XML mapping that would work? I'd prefer to not even map the column and only use it for joining if possible. If it helps there is a potential discriminator column `login_holder_type` which indicates which table to join to.

It did occur to me to setup an `IClassConvention` but after poking at the passed `IClassInstance` I could not determine any settings which would help me.

```cs
public class UserIdConvention : IClassConvention, IClassConventionAcceptance
{

    public void Apply(IClassInstance instance)
    {
        // do something awesome with instance.Subclasses to
        // specify the use of login_cust_id for subclass joining...
    }

    public void Accept(IAcceptanceCriteria<IClassInspector> criteria)
    {
        criteria.Expect(x => typeof(User).Equals(x.EntityType));
    }
}
```

The lack of a populated Subclasses collection for the passed instance caused me to look for a more specific inspector which [`IParentInspector`](https://github.com/jagregory/fluent-nhibernate/blob/master/src/FluentNHibernate/Conventions/Inspections/IParentInspector.cs) appears to be. Unfortunately [Fluent NHibernate](http://www.fluentnhibernate.org/) does not appear to have corresponding implementations for `IParentInstance`, `IParentConvention` or `IParentConventionAcceptance` like it does for [`IJoinedSubclassInspector`](https://github.com/jagregory/fluent-nhibernate/blob/master/src/FluentNHibernate/Conventions/Inspections/IJoinInspector.cs). While I could probably implement my own before I do I wanted to ensure I wasn't barking up the wrong tree.

Is this sort of subclass id adjustment even possible? Am I missing something obvious in either my map or the [Fluent NHibernate Conventions namespace](https://github.com/jagregory/fluent-nhibernate/tree/master/src/FluentNHibernate/Conventions)? How can I map to a joined subclass with a different column/property than the id of parent?

Comment: Am way out of my territory here, but I googled up [this](http://www.codeproject.com/Questions/235691/Nhibernate-mapping-with-property-ref-on-base-class). Apperantly, in the xml mapping you can use a `property-ref` attribute to map to a non-ID column on the base class. Additionally, you need to specify `foreign-key="none"`. How to express this in Fluent Hibernate I do not know.

Comment: Refactor the database. There's ways to do this that give the other users enough time to adjust to the new situation.

Answer (score 3):

I was able to think of three possible solution to your problem please see my findings below.

### Solution 1: Discriminator based mapping with Join

My initial idea was to use a discriminator based mapping for modelling the inheritance, with each sub-class containing a join with a property ref, i.e

```
<class name="IUser" abstract="true" table="login">
    <id name="Id" column="login_sk">
        <generator class="identity"/>
    </id>
    <discriminator column="login_holder_type" not-null="true" type="System.String"/>

    <subclass name="CustomerUser" discriminator-value="Customer">
        <join table="customer" >
          <key column="cust_id" property-ref="login_cust_id" />
          <property name="DisplayName" column="cust_mail_name"/>
          <property name="RecordChangeName" column="cust_lookup_name" />
        </join>
    </subclass>

    <subclass name="EntityUser" discriminator-value="Entity">
      <join table="entity" >        
        <key column="entity_id" property-ref="login_cust_id" />
        <property name="CompanyName"/>
      </join>
    </subclass>
</class>
```

Unfortunately at this time this feature is supported in Hibernate but not in NHibernate. Please see [here](https://nhibernate.jira.com/browse/NH-1452) and [here](https://nhibernate.jira.com/browse/NH-3143) for the outstanding tickets. Some work has gone towards adding this feature which can be seen on [this](https://github.com/Nicaog/nhibernate-core/tree/NH-1681) fork on github.

### Solution 2: Discriminator based mapping with Many-to-One

Another option is to still use the discriminator based mapping, but use a [`many-to-one`](http://nhforge.org/doc/nh/en/index.html#mapping-declaration-manytoone) mapping within each of the sub-classes, which would allow you to join on the foreign key using a property-ref. This has the disadvantage of requiring separate classes for all of the properties in your customer and entity tables but is a workable solution.

```
<class name="IUser" abstract="true" table="login">
    <id name="Id" column="login_sk">
        <generator class="identity"/>
    </id>
    <discriminator column="login_holder_type" not-null="true" type="System.String"/>

    <subclass name="CustomerUser" discriminator-value="Customer">
        <many-to-one name="CustomerProps" property-ref="login_cust_id" />
    </subclass>

    <subclass name="EntityUser" discriminator-value="entity">
        <many-to-one name="EntityProps" property-ref="login_cust_id" />     
    </subclass>
</class>

<class name="CustomerProps" Table="customer" >
  <id name="Id" column="cust_id">
    <generator class="assigned"/>
  </id>
  <property name="DisplayName" column="cust_mail_name"/>
  <property name="RecordChangeName" column="cust_lookup_name" />
</class>

<class name="EntityProps" Table="entity" >
  <id name="Id" column="entity_id">
    <generator class="assigned"/>
  </id>
  <property name="CompanyName"/>
</class>
```

### Solution 3: Discriminator based mapping with Joins to Updatable Views

The final option is to create an Updatable View in the DB for the customer and entity tables which contains the login_sk field. You can then use `Join` within each sub-class as you wouldn't require the `property-ref`.

```
<class name="IUser" abstract="true" table="login">
    <id name="Id" column="login_sk">
        <generator class="identity"/>
    </id>
    <discriminator column="login_holder_type" not-null="true" type="System.String"/>

    <subclass name="CustomerUser" discriminator-value="Customer">
        <join table="customerView" >
          <key column="login_sk" />
          <property name="DisplayName" column="cust_mail_name"/>
          <property name="RecordChangeName" column="cust_lookup_name" />
        </join>
    </subclass>

    <subclass name="EntityUser" discriminator-value="Entity">
      <join table="entityView" >        
        <key column="login_sk" />
        <property name="CompanyName"/>
      </join>
    </subclass>
</class>
```